# How to mock angular.element.injector().get;

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have controller code like this in an angularjs file...

```
    function sendAnalytics(searchParams) {
        var analyticServiceCall = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('SomeElement');
     };
```

When I run test cases attached with the above controller I get the following error

```
 * TypeError: Cannot call method "get" of undefined in http://localhost:46309/src/soemFolder/someController.js (line XYZ)
```

What I am understanding is, I need to mock angular.element(document.body).injector().get function but how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
  angular.element.fn.extend({ injector: function() { return $injector } });
});
```

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2839)

Comment: THANK YOU :) IT WORKED LIKE CHARM :)