# How do I mock angular.element(document).injector().get('$location'); in jasmine 3.6?

Tags: angular, angularjs

I'm currently facing a problem. I do not know how to mock this method:

```
private angularLocation = angular.element(document).injector().get('$location');
```

I have a hybrid angular app, and this method is used to navigate between angular to angularjs pages. I have tried the suggestion on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68623971/how-to-mock-angular-element-injector-get) but it did not work. See the screenshot below:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo3j2.png)

I am using jasmine 3.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
it('should navigate to a specific path', () => {
  mockLocation.path.and.returnValue('/somePath');

  // Execute some function in your code that eventually calls $location.path()
  yourFunctionUnderTest();

  expect(mockLocation.path).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/somePath');
});
```

You need to inject this while making the call.